# How to read spring boot configuration file in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, configuration, amazon-eks

Im new in Kubernetes and having a hard time making to read application.properties in the deployment. I have attached our ConfigMap as a mounted volume under the /config path.

This is my deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
 metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: default
spec:
 replicas: 2
 selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: myapp
template:
  metadata:
    labels:
     app: myapp
  spec:
    containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: 34343434.dkr.ecr.asia-2.amazonaws.com/myapp:latest
        ports:
         - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: application-properties
          mountPath: /config
      volumes:
      - name: application-properties
        configMap:
          name: application-properties
```

I have created configmap using kubectl command from a file that is located in my local computer.

```
kubectl create configmap application-properties -–from-file=/users/me/application.properties
```

Now the issue is the application.property file which i am setting it using the kubectl configmap is not getting picked up. Can you help me on this?

Comment: are you able to see the content of configmap if its really contain the all the properties ? `kubectl get configmap application-properties  -o yaml`

Comment: yes, i have checked with this command: kubectl describe configmaps application-properties

Comment: @Adiii do you think i have a syntax error , or the way of linking is wrong?

Comment: not describe, the `get` command and check the content below `application.properties: |`

Comment: @Adiii the get command for configmap shows the contents but with all in oneline format. seperated by \n . Seems like broken. :(

Comment: @Adiii should i convert application.properties file to yaml and then create configmap from yaml file?

Comment: that cloud be the issue, it should in proper formate, https://env.simplestep.ca/ try to convert and see if ti work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249029/discussion-between-adiii-and-gippo).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion, the issue was the configmap, instead of the `property` file, it was rendered as a string in the configmap.

```
kubectl get configmap application-properties  -o yaml
>shows the contents but with all in oneline format. separated by \n
```

[Converting it to YAML](https://env.simplestep.ca/) `application.yml` did the trick.